# coordinate system problem

Tags: graphics3d, image, coordinate-transformation

I had an issue about the coordinate system of mathematica. I have a {800,600} image  acquired with a camera. The projection matrix P of the camera is calculated using the calibration task. Now, when I calculate the projection of a known point `{x,y,z}` as `p.{x,y,z,1}={X,Y}` in the image. I remark that the `Y` is not correct and the real value is given by `600-Y`. It seems that the y-axis inversed between the camera and mathematica. Any clarification?

Comment: How do you access the pixels of the image? Remember that you can see an image as a matrix, where the first row is the top row of pixels. This is why `ImageData[image][[1]]` represents the top row.

Comment: @FJRA, I access to pixel using the tool "Get coordinates"

Comment: I see, that's a `Graphics` tool, and those are "plot" coordinates, so they start bottom left. That means that you have to do `height - coordY` to get the row number.

Comment: @FJRA, I see the problem.In fact the camera gives us the indices of the pixel not the coordinates. So when I compare the {X,Y} of the camera and the Get indices I am getting the same.

Comment: @FJRA, so I have to use the ImageData[] to get the right value

Comment: Yes, I think `ImageData` is the best function if you need to access directly the pixel values. Check the documentation, maybe some of its options are useful for your case of use.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19590/discussion-between-developer2000-and-fjra).

Comment: Here is an extended discussion of the various graphics/image coordinate systems: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32377/1783